# Change the border color of a td item fails, tried css and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a WordPress plugin to generate a overview of members. It works great but I want to change the divider line between the rows.

Sadly there isn't a class applied to each row.

The generated HTML code looks like the following:

```
<tr id="Dentista" class="wowclass-1">
    <td style="vertical-align:middle;padding:10px">4</td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle;padding:10px">Dentista</td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle;padding:10px">100</td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle;padding:10px">Warrior</td>
    <td style="vertical-align:middle;padding:10px">4</td>
</tr>
```

Each td brings a border with itself, which looks like this:

```
table.wow-armory-table, .wow-armory-table td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4c4c!important;
}
```

But anything I try to change the color of this border fails, I tried to add CSS but I guess it wouldn't show up because the static !important inside the CSS.

Also tried Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('table.wow-armory-table').css(["border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;"]);
    });
</script>
```

[Link to the site](http://beta.pr0b.com/rooster)

Does anyone in here have a idea how to fix it? I just want to change the color of the line.

Comment: The original CSS does contain quite a lot of `!important`s. Bad design. See if you can get rid of at least some of them, then you won't need any `!important` of your own.

Comment: I don't have all my CSS trys saved anymore, but it been trys like this: td{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}

Comment: It looks like the plug-in is actually injecting `style` tags into your HTML (not the `head`...more at the bottom of the page . This suggest that the border styling should be a setting inside the plug-in itself.

Comment: @pr0b Wait, you have a style block at the end of the body. Correct that first.

Comment: @MrLister There's actually two IIRC...I'm not up on WP but would a plug-in inject a `style` tag like that? Seems inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

You're using CSS files and an inline CSS at the very end that's overwritting everything.

```
<style>a.wowclass-1 {color: #C79C6E!important}a.wowclass-2 {color: #F58CBA!important}a.wowclass-3 {color: #ABD473!important}a.wowclass-4 {color: #FFF569!important}a.wowclass-5 {color: #FFFFFF!important}a.wowclass-6 {color: #C41F3B!important}a.wowclass-7 {color: #0070DE!important}a.wowclass-8 {color: #69CCF0!important}a.wowclass-9 {color: #9482C9!important}a.wowclass-10 {color: #00FF96!important}a.wowclass-11 {color: #FF7D0A!important}</style><style>.wow-armory-table .wowclass-1 {color: #C79C6E}.wow-armory-table .wowclass-2 {color: #F58CBA}.wow-armory-table .wowclass-3 {color: #ABD473}.wow-armory-table .wowclass-4 {color: #FFF569}.wow-armory-table .wowclass-5 {color: #FFFFFF}.wow-armory-table .wowclass-6 {color: #C41F3B}.wow-armory-table .wowclass-7 {color: #0070DE}.wow-armory-table .wowclass-8 {color: #69CCF0}.wow-armory-table .wowclass-9 {color: #9482C9}.wow-armory-table .wowclass-10 {color: #00FF96}.wow-armory-table .wowclass-11 {color: #FF7D0A}table.dataTable tr.odd {background-color: #202020}table.dataTable tr.even {background-color: #3b3b3b}table.dataTable tr.odd td.sorting_1 {background-color: #202020}table.dataTable tr.even td.sorting_1 {background-color: #3b3b3b}table.wow-armory-table , .wow-armory-table td {border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4c4c!important;}.characters-by-class-container hr {background-color: #0a0a0a;}</style>
```

You need to change

```
 wow-armory-table td {border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4c4c!important;}
```

to this

```
 wow-armory-table td {border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
```

Also you shouldn't be using `!important` as much as you are. If you load the correct CSS in order, you shouldn't have a problem.

Because you have it listed as `!important` declared in the inline CSS, you won't be able to overwrite it with jQuery or your CSS file.

Comment: Sadly i dont have access to the css files, the css and html code gets generated by a wordpress plugin.

Comment: Well the problem still exists there. So it looks like you need to identify why wordpress is putting !important on everything and resolve that. Then you can change the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.wow-armory-table td').css(["border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;"]);
    });
</script>
```

Or just add

```
.wow-armory-table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

to your css.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wordpress than first add a plugin CUSTOM CSS and that put your CSS in it and it will override the existing css. or may be your theme have builtin custom css function.

```
 table.wow-armory-table, .wow-armory-table td {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4c4c!important;
}
```

i hope this will resolve your problem.